# Python : Detect EOF in test data

Tags: python, input, automated-tests, eof

I got the problem with pass the automated test in python. And I think the reason is my program does not end when the test data ends.

This program builds a network between two IP adresses with command like:

- `B 100.100.100.1 100.100.100.2`

It means: build connection between IP1 and IP2 in both ways.

There is also second command to test if the connection exists.

- `T 100.100.100.1 100.100.100.3`

And the program prints 'T' if its possioble and 'N' if not.

Lets say we got entry data like:

```
B 100.100.100.1 100.100.100.2
B 100.100.100.1 100.100.100.3
B 100.100.100.10 100.100.100.11
T 100.100.100.1 100.100.100.3
T 100.100.100.10 100.100.100.2
T 100.100.100.10 100.100.100.11
B 100.100.100.11 100.100.100.2
T 100.100.100.10 100.100.100.3
T 100.100.100.100 100.100.100.103
```

Then expected output is :

```
T
N
T
T
N
```

My program prints out correct values but does not relise if the test data is over and works until empty line in input is detected. But it requires hit 1 more 'Enter' into command line to send this line and automated test wouldn't send it.

I think i need to read all input data at once, but i dont have idea how to ignore '\n' at the end of every line and detect only 1 'enter' at the very end of the input.

I hope that the problem description is clear. Here is the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Graph:

    def __init__(self,vertices):
        self.V= vertices
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)
    def addVerticle(self):
        self.V+=1

    def addEdge(self,u,v):
        self.graph[u].append(v)

    def graph_keys(self):
        return self.graph.keys()

    def isReachable(self, s, d):
        visited =[False]*(self.V)
        queue=[]
        queue.append(s)
        visited[s] = True

        while queue:
            n = queue.pop(0)
            if n == d:
                 return True
            for i in self.graph[n]:
                if visited[i] == False:
                    queue.append(i)
                    visited[i] = True
        return False

ip_list={}
counter=0
g = Graph(0)
while True:
    u_in = [x for x in input().split()]
    if not u_in:
        break
    action = u_in[0]
    start = u_in[1]
    end = u_in[2]
    if action == 'B':
        if start not in ip_list.keys():
            ip_list[start]=counter
            counter+=1
        if end not in ip_list.keys():
            ip_list[end]=counter
            counter+=1
        start = ip_list[start]
        end = ip_list[end]
        if start not in g.graph_keys():
            g.addVerticle()
        if end not in g.graph_keys():
            g.addVerticle()
        g.addEdge(start,end)
        g.addEdge(end,start)
    elif action =='T':
        if start not in ip_list.keys() or end not in ip_list.keys():
            print('N')
            continue
        if g.isReachable(ip_list[start],ip_list[end]):
            print('T')
        else:
            print('N')
```

Comment: Maybe you can write the number of lines first or read data from file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below (assuming input is comimg from a file)

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
  lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
for line in lines:
  print(line)
  # TODO - your logic goes here
```

input.txt

```
B 100.100.100.1 100.100.100.2
B 100.100.100.1 100.100.100.3
B 100.100.100.10 100.100.100.11
T 100.100.100.1 100.100.100.3
T 100.100.100.10 100.100.100.2
T 100.100.100.10 100.100.100.11
B 100.100.100.11 100.100.100.2
T 100.100.100.10 100.100.100.3
T 100.100.100.100 100.100.100.103
```

Comment: Thank you for reply :D But what if the input is coming from the command line as a raw copy/paste text ? :/

Comment: In this case there should be a way to 'signal' that the line is the last line. Example `T 100.100.100.10 100.100.100.3 L` - the last L can tell the code that this is the last line.

Comment: Reading input from file works great, but i dont know if the automated test is using this, and what is the name of file i should read from. Its a blank test that source code isn't viewable. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: If the test are automated, I think it makes sense that input will come from files - isnt it?

Comment: If so, what is the default name for file with the test data? Or i need to gues? xD

Comment: Only you and your team have answers to those questions. Try to talk to the team and collect information.